# Playframework 2.0 onError get request body

Tags: java, error-handling, request, playframework-2.0

I have overrided the method `public Result onError(RequestHeader rh, Throwable t)`, but this class `RequestHeader` doesn't seems to have request body saved - [API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html)

Anybody knows how to get request body in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution - I overrided `public Action<?> onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod)` where I save `RequestBody` which I can use in `onError`.

:)

```
private RequestBody lastBody;

@Override
public Action<?> onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
    lastBody = request.body();
    return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
}

@Override
public Result onError(RequestHeader rh, Throwable t) {  
    //here i can get the body
    System.out.println(lastBody);

    return play.mvc.Results.internalServerError(errorPage.render());
}
```